# How to change just one item of QCombobox to editable by user

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I have 4 items in my `QCombobox`,

```
'Bryce king'
'James White'
'Russo W'
'Custom Manager'
```

So, when I click on  `"Custom Manager"`, it should change to editable and I must be able to enter my own desired name.

I have tried to achieve this behavior using QtCreator, and in the properties, I can set it to editable but that would make all items editable instead of just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your combobox's editable property is set to false.

Then you can use the [`QComboBox::currentIndexChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) signal and check the value of the current index and then make the combobox editable. Example:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    if (arg1 == "Custom Manager") {
        ui->comboBox->setEditable(true);
    }
    else {
        ui->comboBox->setEditable(false);
    }
}
```

Moreover, if you want to save the value to the edited text use [`QComboBox::currentTextChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentTextChanged) signal:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentTextChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    qDebug() << arg1;
    ui->comboBox->setItemText(ui->comboBox->currentIndex(), arg1);
}
```